# How to specify &mdash; as an attribute value in JSF?

Tags: jsf, attributes, special-characters, facelets

When I tried the next code:

```
<o:weekSwitcher splitter="&mdash;"/>
```

I received error "unresolved entity reference mdash". How can I work around this issue?

Comment: Note that this is a XML error, not a JSF error. In other words, you're using Facelets and its parser is choking on a plain HTML entity. You need a XML entity instead, see McDowell. A HTML entity would have worked in JSP.

Comment: @BalusC: I'm trying to make work CDATA section but not very successfully yet. Do you have an example with CDATA?

Comment: @BalusC: ok, but what if I've got 10 lines of html which I want to past as an attribute value? using multiple &lt; &gt; is not very convenient..

Comment: If it's static, do it once and forget it. If it's dynamic, make it a bean property and escape XML entities using Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Unicode character entity `&#x2014;`